# Creating a custom shape in konva.js using path2d?

Tags: javascript, konvajs, konva

Using d3 for some shape calculations, then drawing with Konva.js. Creating a new shape from a svg path string. The shape is drawn, but `fillStrokeShape` doesn't seem to apply any styles.

The documentions says:

> We can use the renderer to access the HTML5 Canvas context, and to use
> special methods like context.fillStrokeShape(shape) which
> automatically handles filling, stroking, and applying shadows.

I am guessing this is the case because the path gets drawn using `stroke()` or `fill()`.

```
let res = 'M-258.4308858485627,28.5215223914706A260,260,0,0,1,-241.23905423140914,-96.97277305272468Q0,0,-258.4308858485627,28.5215223914706Z'
```

```
    let shape = new Konva.Shape({
        stroke: 'blue',
        fill: 'green',
        strokeWidth: 1,
        rotation: 90,
        sceneFunc: function (ctx, shape) {   
          ctx.beginPath()

          ctx.stroke(new Path2D(res))
        
    
          ctx.fillStrokeShape(shape)
        }
      })
```

Possible solution would be to convert the svg path string into canvas instructions, then use context.moveTo, etc ... draw the path. But using `Path2D` should already do this for you.

Anyone know why `fillStrokeShape` is not working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See docs of konvajs:

https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Path.html
https://konvajs.org/docs/shapes/Custom.html

I think Path2D is not needed.

Insert your res in Konva.Path.data